# Loading an image URL from Xamarin Forms PCL to PageRenderer in Android project fails

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

I am passing an URL string of an image from a website, these images appear in a listview on the PCL project, the URL of the image passes fine to the Android Custom Renderer, but loading the image with MonoDroidToolKit fails with the following error:

Unhandled Exception:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key

From PCL(passing attachment information):

```
    public partial class ImageViewPage : ContentPage
   {
    public ImageViewPage(Attachment imageItem)
    {
        if (imageItem == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        BindingContext = imageItem;
        _imageItem = imageItem.url;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string _imageItem { get; private set; }
}
```

In Android Custom Renderer:

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ImageViewPage),typeof(ImageViewRenderer))]
 namespace BibleCodesApp.Droid
 {
 public class ImageViewRenderer : PageRenderer
 {
    global::Android.Views.View view;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    Activity activity;
    ImageView imageView;

    private string imageItem
    {
        get
        {
            var imageViewPage = Element as ImageViewPage;
            return imageViewPage == null
                ? null
                : imageViewPage._imageItem;
        }
    }

  protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page>e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        activity = this.Context as Activity;
       view =  activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate
       (Resource.Layout.ImageView,this,false);

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity, 512);
        imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image_view);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageItem, imageView, -1);
     }

   }
}
```

The layout in Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <BibleCodesApp.Droid.ScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you also using a custom view that inherits ImageView? Or is `BibleCodesApp.Droid.ScaleImageView` meant to just be an `ImageView`?

Comment: I have a custom view for the ImageView, but either way if I use the default ImageView alone, same result.

I removed the ImageView and tested with a textview:

textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_view);
textView.Text = imageItem;

Still doesn't work, but when I debug it results fine in Output Console:

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"Image Url: " + imageItem);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct solution:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ZoomImage), typeof(ZoomImageRenderer))]
```

namespace WPAppTemplate.Droid
{
    public class ZoomImageRenderer : ImageRenderer
    {
        private ZoomImage _zoomImage;
        private ScaleImageView _scaleImage;

```
    protected async override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            _zoomImage = (ZoomImage)e.NewElement;

            // create the scale image and set it as the native control so it's available
            _scaleImage = new ScaleImageView(Context, null);
            _scaleImage.ZoomImage = _zoomImage;
            SetNativeControl(_scaleImage);
            await LoadImage();
        }
    }

    protected async override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == ZoomImage.AspectProperty.PropertyName
            || e.PropertyName == ZoomImage.HeightProperty.PropertyName
            || e.PropertyName == ZoomImage.WidthProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            _scaleImage.ZoomToAspect();
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == ZoomImage.SourceProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            await LoadImage();
            _scaleImage.ZoomToAspect();
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == ZoomImage.CurrentZoomProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            _scaleImage.ZoomFromCurrentZoom();
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == ZoomImage.MaxZoomProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            _scaleImage.UpdateMaxScaleFromZoomImage();
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == ZoomImage.MinZoomProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            _scaleImage.UpdateMinScaleFromZoomImage();
        }
    }

    private async Task LoadImage()
    {
        var image = await (new ImageLoaderSourceHandler()).LoadImageAsync(_zoomImage.Source, Context);
        try
        {
            if (image != null && image.ByteCount > 0)
                _scaleImage.SetImageBitmap(image);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // catch an image loading failure
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to load bitmap. Exception: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see it now:
You are inflating your new view, but never actually adding it to the page!

You should call

```
        this.ViewGroup.AddView(view);
```

after your `imageLoader.DisplayImage` call at the end of `OnElementChanged`

Comment: Thanks one step closer lol, it opens the page properly now, but it's completely blank, no visual elements.

In the debug console it shows:

01-27 20:07:57.113 W/art     (23752): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md501cb5cd6e77056981e9da485897267ed.ImageViewRenderer
01-27 20:07:57.123 D/Mono    (23752): Assembly Ref addref BibleCodesApp.Droid[0xb3f159e0] -> System[0xb47d7500]: 16